# How to align node with one node, minimum width from another node?

Tags: positioning, nodes, width

Suppose I have two nodes (A and B in example) already defined. Suppose I want a third node C to be (e.g.) below node A and stretching so far to line up with node B.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  % two example nodes, position and size do not matter: 
  \node [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=3cm, draw] (a) {A}; 
  \node [right=1cm of a, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw] (b) {B};

  % new node to align and size: 
  \node [below=1cm of a.south west, anchor=north west, draw,
  minimum width=5.5cm, % <--- this should not be necessary!! 
  ] (c) {C}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I can get this done by manual calculation of minimum width, but that is of course ugly. I could define new coordinate like ([yshift=-1cm]b.south east) and then do fit, but that is ugly as well.

Is there a concise, easy to write and read, relative way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `ext.positioning-plus` library of my [`tikz-ext`ensions package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) this is easily done.

The key `west below=… of <node>` means basically the same as your `below=… of <node>.south west, anchor=north west`. And the `-` indicates that the following nodes should be spanned horizontally. (There's also `|` and `+`.)

Using both `(a)` and `(b)` hear means that the new node will be `1cm` below a box around `a` and `b`. If `b` is lower than `a` but you want `1cm` below `a`, use `west below=… of a, span horizontal=(a)(b)`.

This uses the `positioning` library and the `fit` library but you don't need to load them manually.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.positioning-plus}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  % two example nodes, position and size do not matter: 
  \node[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=3cm, draw]                    (a){A}; 
  \node[right=1cm of a, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw](b){B};

  % new node to align and size: 
  \node [west below=1cm of -(a)(b), draw] (c) {C}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this library. Need to read into it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks really great - definitely have to read up on it! Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `let` syntax (requires the `calc` library).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  % two example nodes, position and size do not matter: 
  \node [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=3cm, draw] (a) {A}; 
  \node [right=1cm of a, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw] (b) {B};

  % new node to align and size: 
  \path let \p1=(a.west), \p2=(b.east) in (a) to (b) node
    [below=1cm of a.south west, anchor=north west, draw, minimum width=\x2-\x1] (c) {C}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, that is similar to coordinate calculation, but easier to take the difference. Thanks for reminding me here.